# 6v switch to power something much larger

Tags: power-supply, power, switches, switching, basic

I feel like I'm making this more complicated than it has to be. If I have a 6v switch like this [one](https://www.adafruit.com/product/915?gclid=CjwKCAiA-KzSBRAnEiwAkmQ155idfmEu5V2OAK60Afvpi6SmxCT5ldXTQFzApmMy5pk7btH5ioxoGRoCoUQQAvD_BwE), can I use it to turn on something like a 110v ~26A power supply? The current is far too high for the switch - I know that.

So I figure I should use the switch to control a relay kinda like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PQ7Y8ZU) that CAN handle the amps. But that would mean converting 110 AC (from the wall) to 6v DC to run through the switch and to the relay which I think is wrong. Wouldn't I need to convert it into a signal somehow?

I'm a software guy with very little EE knowledge. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The switch is rated at 3A / 250VDC not 6V. The 6V listed is only for the lamp in the switch. Because of that error I am not convinced you are really switching a 26A power supply. Perhaps you should post the power supply link too.

Comment: Good catch! But yes, the power supply I want to switch is a KL-4030.

Comment: That comes up as a stepper motor driver.. got a link?

Comment: Oh dang. That power supply is only 3A - not sure where I got 26 BUT the question still stands. How would I make something rated for 3A switch something larger than 3?

Comment: Use a contactor (relay).

Comment: Seems a bit inefficient compared to something like a transistor. Thanks!

Comment: You can't easily use a transistor for AC, and there are all kinds of isolation issues. There are solid state methods, but I would not recommend them to anyone who is not VERY experienced in EE. A solid state relay may be your best bet.

Comment: This is going nowhere fast. VTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Trevor is right - use a Contactor. Thanks for the help in my inexperience!